# Warning when opening xls file which is exported from html table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I used the following code. I can download the file with extension .xls. When I open this downloaded file I receive this warning:

> The file you are trying to open, 'Statement.xls', is in a different
>   format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is
>   not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do
>   you want to open the file now?

Javascript Code:

```
var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('exportable').innerHTML], {
        type: "application/vnd.ms-excel;" });
saveAs(blob, "Statement.xls");`
```

HTML code:

```
`<table id="exportable">
   <tbody>
    <tr><th>ColumnOne</th><th>ColumnTwo</th><th>ColumnThree</th></tr>
    <tr><td>row1Col1</td><td>row1Col2</td><td>row1Col3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row2Col1</td><td>row2Col2</td><td>row2Col3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row3Col1</td><td>row3Col2</td><td>test</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>`
```

External library:

```
https://rawgithub.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/master/FileSaver.js
```

Comment: Can you show us the warning you get?

Comment: I just attach image plz check it for that warning

Comment: what happens if you save it as `.xlsx` ? Your next test should be what happens if you set the mimetype that was defined for the newer Versions of Excel: `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

Comment: And by the way: it would not hurt to mention the error message as text instead of a screenshot. Some people are using search engines to search for certain error Messages and it is easier to find text if it is used as such.

Answer (score 2):

Office and Excel are able to cope with two different file formats. As those formats are totally different from the inside (the old one is binary, the new one is simply zipped up XML) different extensions and mimetypes were assigned to these formats.
Obviously you are creating a file with the new format and assign it the old extension. Excel complains about that.

Change your code to look like this:

```
var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('exportable').innerHTML], {
        type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" });
saveAs(blob, "Statement.xlsx");
```

For the sake of learning you might want to have a look at your created file with a hex editor. 
Others had similar issues, have a look here: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/139

Comment: Actually Excel can handle html with tables as input as well but it doesn't have any proper mimetype as far as I know (though text/html could possibly work). This makes it really easy to export simple tabular data from the web to Excel but it is in 99% of the cases documents from an untrusted source so the warning might be hard to get around.

Comment: The following warning is comming:'The file you are trying to open', is in different format than specified by extension. Verify that the file is not currupted and is form a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?'

Comment: is there need to set any parameter to html table?

Comment: @Dnyanesh Open the file in an editor or hexviewer and show us the content.

Comment: i still have the same warning, any clues on this matter?

Answer (score -2):

When saving file with *.xls extension,  file type should be set to "application/xls"

Since file type and extension will be matching, you shouldn't get any warning.